# Unable to create a jpackage installer on Fedora but it works in Ubuntu, macOS, and Windows

Tags: java, linux, fedora, rpm, jpackage

I run the following jpackage command in Ubuntu 20.04 with OpenJDK 16.01:

```
jpackage --name MyApp --app-version 1.0.0 --icon /some/path/bigLogo.png --input ./ --main-jar my_app.jar
```

and it creates a ".deb" installer file.  When I run the same command on my freshly installed Fedora 34 with OpenJDK 16.02, I get the error message:

```
Error: Invalid or unsupported type: [null]
```

When I specifically identify the installer type via "--type rpm", I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid or unsupported type: [rpm]
```

When I do "jpackage --help" and look at the help for --type, it tells me:

```
Valid values are: {"app-image", "rpm", "deb"}
```

Ubuntu lists the same valid values, but if I give it the supposedly valid type of 'rpm', it gives the same error of 'rpm' not being supported (but 'deb' works). The help is definitely not totally static.  When I check the help in macOS, it tells me:

```
Valid values are: {"app-image", "dmg", "pkg"}
```

Have I stumbled across an openjdk bug or am I missing some setup that needs to be performed on the JDK prior to use?  All I've done for either Linux install is download the tar ball, set JAVA_HOME, and add $JAVA_HOME/bin to PATH.

My goal is to create an 'rpm' installer.  If someone can give specific steps how I would do that with JDK 16, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: *All I've done for either Linux install is download the tar ball,* Which tarball?

Comment: From here:
https://jdk.java.net/16/ .  I got this file:
 https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk16.0.2/d4a915d82b4c4fbb9bde534da945d746/7/GPL/openjdk-16.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

I got 16.01 from the same place whenever that was the most recent version.  Also tried the EA of 17 - also from same page.

Comment: My guess is that since that is package-system-neutral, it won't know how to build an rpm installer. Try a jdk packaged in an rpm instead

Comment: I tried installing the latest via "sudo dnf install java-latest-openjdk-devel", which installs 16.0.2 rpms then made sure I had switched to the new version via 'sudo alternatives --config java' and tried jpackage again.  Same error.

Comment: Can't help sorry. I've done .deb, .msi and .exe. Try setting the output to super verbose and see if it helps.

Comment: As an aside, if that guess were correct, the tarball probably wouldn't know how to build .deb packages on Ubuntu either.  But I just tried 16.02 on Ubuntu and jpackage can build .deb packages.

Comment: With any luck there will be someone along who's done this

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-786E15C0-2CE7-4BDF-9B2F-AC1C57249134), it looks like the rpm-build package needs to be installed